# Assembly analyzing system() function called in C

Tags: c, assembly, intel

So I made a very simple C program to study how C works on the inside. It has just 1 line in the main() excluding return 0:

```
system("cls");
```

If I use ollydebugger to analyze this program It will show something like this(text after the semicolons are comments generated by ollydebugger.

```
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],test_1.004030EC     ; ||ASCII "cls"
CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.system>                ; |\system
```

Can someone explain what this means, and if I want to change the "cls" called in the system() to another command, where is the "cls" stored? And how do I modify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using 32 bit Windows system, with its corresponding [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) (the assumptions used when functions are called).

```
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],test_1.004030EC
```

Is equivalent to a `push 4030ech` instruction, that simply store the address of the string *cls* on the stack.
This is the way parameters are passed to functions and tell us that the string *cls* is at address `4030ech`.

```
CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.system>                ; |\system
```

This is the call to the `system` function from the *CRT*.
The *JMP* in the name is due how linking works by default with Visual Studio compilers and linkers.

So those two lines are simply passing the address of the string to the `system` function.

If you want do modify it you need to check if it is in a writable section (I think is not) by checking the *PE Sections*, your debugger may have a tool for that. Or you could just try anyway the following:
Inspect the memory at `4030ech`, you will see the string, try editing it (this is debugger dependent).

**Note**: I use the TASM notation for hex numbers, i.e. `123h` means `0x123` in C notation.

Comment: So how can I get the data that is stored in test_1.004030EC? And so the value in test_1.004030EC is moved to DWORD PTR SS:[ESP]. so can I see the moved value in the ESP Register?

Comment: @Dashadower it is moved into `[ESP]`, **note the square brackets**. It means that the DWORD `4030ech` is stored at the address inside the register `ESP`. So if `ESP` contains `1000h` the DWORD is stored at `1000h` not into `ESP`